# Running device firmware on a computer

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization, firmware

I was wondering how I would go about running device firmware in a virtual machine on Windows 7 or some other way on windows 7. I am specifically thinking of running the [Broadband-Hamnet](http://www.broadband-hamnet.org/) firmware for the Linksys WRT54 series routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot run the device firmware for a router on your computer.

Your router is almost certainly an ARM architecture CPU with some very custom hardware such as an Ethernet switch and ADSL router alongside. Your computer is an x86-64 CPU with a very different set of surrounding peripherals. You cannot run code meant for one architecture on another.

ARM devices tend to be such custom devices that it is often difficult to run the firmware of one device on any other device without major work, let alone changing the underlying CPU architecture as well.

Comment: What about on a Raspberry Pi? I believe they have ARM processors.

Comment: @NoviceLinux-WindowsGeek - ARM is design differently than x86 which means Linux compiled on ARM must be configured for the device.  While both would be ARM its unlikely the software would work without extensive modifications

Comment: *"You cannot run the device firmware for a router on your computer"* -- I have heard of people using (ARM) emulators in a VM to do this.  *"surrounding peripherals"* -- That sounds redundant, just like "remote peripheral" is an oxymoron.